# Safari and iphone block redirect from iframe

Tags: iphone, iframe, safari, ads

I'm currently experiencing an issue with links in an iframe. This links have multiple redirects (ads links). 
The iframe is usually placed in a domain that is different from mine. When a user with an iphone (using safari) lands on this page and clicks one of the link I provide, it's redirected to a blank page.

This does not happen with chrome or firefox, but only with safari and only with iphones. With chrome and firefox the user is redirected to the correct page.

Moreover, and this is really weird, if on safari I press the link and do one of the following options, "Open" or "Open in a new tab", the redirect works perfectly.

There is some policy in safari that blocks the redirects? both sites are under ssl?

This is how I render links:

Thank you very much!